# Why is $\mathbb{R}^2$ not a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-space-isomorphism

Lets suppose we have the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $(x,y,z)\in V$ then $W=(x,y,0)$ is a subspace of $V$ but $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not one as $(x,y)\notin V$(with $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.) But often we consider groups, rings, fields, or vector spaces up to isomorphism. Now as $W$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, shouldn't $\mathbb{R}^2$ also be a subspace of $V$?

Comment: There is a canonical injective homomorphism  from $\mathbf R^2$ to $\mathbf R^3$.

Comment: Being a subspace of something else is not closed under isomorphism. For instance consider a similar case for sets. $\{a,b\} \cong \{1,2\}$ in the sense that they have the same number of elements, but $\{a,b\} $ is not considered a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @Improve : but we clearly say that $\Bbb Q$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ but usually $\Bbb R$ is defined as a quotient of Cauchy sequences of elements of $\Bbb Q$! So two totally different kind of objects. **BUT** there is a canonical isomorphism between $\Bbb Q$ and the convergent Cauchy sequences of $\Bbb Q$

Comment: So this means that one is not allowed to cosider vectorspaces up to isomorphism?

Comment: Two vectorspaces of the same dimension are "the same". The problem is when you want to identify a vector-space with $k<n$ dimensions to a subspace of a $n$ dimensional vector spaces : this demand a choice of basis, so it's not canonical. See my answer : what space would be $\Bbb R^2$ in $\Bbb R^3$?

Answer (score 4):

It's very close to a "semantic" distinction: namely, the difference between *equality* and *isomorphism*. The latter is an equivalence relation, and preserves all the *algebraic* qualities, but not necessarily the *identity* of the set-elements involved.

To a lay person, it seems intuitively obvious that the $xy$-plane (what we use as a model for $\Bbb R^2$) is a subset of the $xyz$-space (what we use as a model for $\Bbb R^3$), but this identification depends, in an essential way, on identifying certain distinguished *basis* vectors (what we choose to use as axes). This choice is not *inherent* in $\Bbb R^3$ as a vector space, and the "conventional" way is somewhat arbitrary.

Put another way, there are, in fact, an infinite number of ways to extend the Euclidean plane to Euclidean $3$-space, and the most we can say "universally" is that each way results in a $2$-dimensional subspace of a $3$-dimensional space-only the dimensions are invariant-the "coordinate systems" we use may differ radically (resulting in perhaps weird numerical "coordinates").

That said, if we assign our Euclidean plane an orthonormal basis (and this can always be done), there are then basically just "two" ways to extend this to an orthonormal basis for a Euclidean $3$-space it lives in: that is we have just two choice for a unit normal vector to this plane. Note that although this narrows the possiblities down, it still does not uniquely determine the result: two is not one.

The usual convention is to determine the "positive" unit normal by "the right-hand rule", this is the same as assigning a sign to the *pseudo-vector* $\mathbf{e_1} \times \mathbf{e_2}$, which determines which *orientation* we have.

As others have pointed out above, this corresponds to "embedding" the ordered basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ into the ordered basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ via the linear isomorphism: $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,0)$. Although the former is a pair, and the latter is a triple, in practice they behave and calculate no differently.

Answer (score 1):

A subset of a vector space is a subspace iff (either by definition or by proof) it has the same zero and "closed" under the same addition and multiplication; but, clearly, the zero in $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ is $(0,0)$, which is $\neq (0,0,0)$, the zero of $\Bbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: Would the downvoter provide your higher opinion?

Comment: I think it was a serial downvoter, as I think all the answers were downvoted

Comment: @Tryss Oh, yes, it could be. :)

Comment: @Gudson Chou Yes, mine is downvoted too.

Comment: And mine too was... Some people have strange hobbies

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are isomorph... as are many other subspaces :

Is $\Bbb R^2$

- $\{ (x,y,0) \in \Bbb R^3 \}$
- $\{ (x,0,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \}$
- $\{ (0,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \}$
- any other 2 dimensional space?

There is no "canonic" subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ that you can identify to $\Bbb R^2$

Answer (score 0):

$V$ consists of $3$-tuples of real numbers $(x, y, z)$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ only consists of ordered pairs $(x, y)$